# What OCRASuite value uses 'Protectimus' in OATH Challenge-Response Algorithm?

Tags: security, hash, ocra, totp

I have problem with OCRA generation, the client and server need to agree on one or two values of OCRASuite but I can't find any information about OCRASuite on official PROTECTIMUS site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check out the following OCRASuite:

**OCRA-1:HOTP-SHA1-6:QA40-T1M**